# Turbogears2: App not starting as sub-package

Tags: python-3.x, turbogears2, turbogears

I'm trying to deploy TurboGears as the sub-package `frontend` of my main application `MainApp`. Following, the structure of my project:

```
.
├── MainApp
│   ├── MainApp.egg-info
│   ├── backend
│   ├── frontend
│   └── __init__.py
├── LICENSE.txt
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── development.ini
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── test.ini
```

Unfortunately, I always get an error when trying to start it with `gearbox serve --reload --debug` in the project folder:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'MainApp.frontend' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I understand that this is due to the definition in the `development.ini`:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:MainApp.frontend
```

I tried different alternatives, calling `egg:MainApp` or `egg:frontend`, also inside the `MainApp` folder with the `development.ini` copied over - nothing worked. What am I missing? Is this even possible?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.

Basically I did three things to solve this

1. I used `egg:MainApp` in the `development.ini`
2. I changed the packages in setup.py from `packages=find_packages(where='MainApp', exclude=['ez_setup'])` to `packages=find_packages(exclude=['ez_setup'])`
3. I ran `pip install -e .` in the project folder again, which created the necessary .egg-info folder